# ¿Como Cambiar el foco entre los Item de 2 Recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Tengo 2 RecyclerView con sus 2 adaptadores para inflarlos.
Estoy recorriendo sus item con las flechas del teclado y poniéndole un marco al item seleccionado.
mientras tengo 1 recyclerview todo funciona bien pero cuando pongo 2 no puedo hacer que el foco se mantenga en el segundo Recyclerview.
Porque ni bien pongo el foco en el segundo se pasa al primero y estoy atorado en eso.

No se si estoy formando bien los Recyclerview en el xml ya que veo que al intercambiar de posicion los recyclerview en el xml se sigue teniendo el problema con el de abajo. Dandome a entender que el problema puede estar en el diseño del XML.

espero alguien conozca de trabajar el foco con el teclado y recyclerview.

desde ya Muchas Gracias.
comparto mi código.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/clcontenido"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
       >
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvpendientes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="#CDCDCD"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rv1"
            >
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvantenciones"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="#CDCDCD"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rv2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            >
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

y este mi java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView rv_pendientes;
    private RecyclerView rv_atenciones;
    private ArrayList<String> lista_pendientes = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> lista_atenciones = new ArrayList<>();
    private Adapter_pendientes adapter_pendientes;
    private Adapter_atenciones adapter_atenciones;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //consulta_pendiente();
        //consulta_atencion();
        rv_atenciones = findViewById(R.id.rvantenciones);
        rv_pendientes = findViewById(R.id.rvpendientes);
        rv_atenciones.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(rv_atenciones.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        rv_pendientes.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(rv_pendientes.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        rv_atenciones.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        rv_pendientes.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        adapter_atenciones = new Adapter_atenciones(lista_atenciones);
        adapter_pendientes = new Adapter_pendientes(lista_pendientes);
        adapter_atenciones.actualizarAlturaElemento(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        adapter_pendientes.actualizarAlturaElemento(RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        rv_atenciones.setAdapter(adapter_atenciones);
        rv_pendientes.setAdapter(adapter_pendientes);
        rv_atenciones.requestFocus();
        adapter_atenciones.setSelectedPosition_atenciones(0);

    }
    private class Adapter_atenciones extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_atenciones.ViewHolder> {
        private List<String> data;
        private int selectedPosition_atenciones = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
        private int alturaElemento = GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        public void setSelectedPosition_atenciones(int position) {
            selectedPosition_atenciones = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
        public Adapter_atenciones(List<String> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_comandas_atenciones, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
        public void actualizarAlturaElemento(int nuevaAltura) {
            alturaElemento = nuevaAltura;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        private int getScreenWidth() {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            return displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.textView_atenciones.setText(data.get(position));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams parametros = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    /*width*/ RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    /*height*/ RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
            holder.textView_atenciones.setLayoutParams(parametros);
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(3, 3, 3, 3);
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
            if (position == selectedPosition_atenciones) {
                holder.textView_atenciones.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_border_comanda);
            } else {
                holder.textView_atenciones.setBackgroundResource(0);
            }
            int screenWidth = getScreenWidth();
            int itemWidth = screenWidth / 5;
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = itemWidth;
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
        }
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView textView_atenciones;
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textView_atenciones = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewcomandas_atenciones);
                textView_atenciones.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int previousSelectedPosition = selectedPosition_atenciones;
                        selectedPosition_atenciones = getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();
                        notifyItemChanged(previousSelectedPosition);
                        notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition_atenciones);
                    }
                });
                textView_atenciones.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            int itemCount = adapter_atenciones.getItemCount();
                            switch (keyCode) {
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                                    if (selectedPosition_atenciones > 0) {
                                        selectedPosition_atenciones--;
                                        rv_atenciones.smoothScrollToPosition(selectedPosition_atenciones);
                                        adapter_atenciones.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                                    if (selectedPosition_atenciones < itemCount - 1) {
                                        selectedPosition_atenciones++;
                                        rv_atenciones.smoothScrollToPosition(selectedPosition_atenciones);
                                        adapter_atenciones.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                                    //showAlertDialog(selectedPosition);
                                    break;
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB:
                                    adapter_pendientes.setSelectedPosition_pendientes(0);
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"TAB a Pendientes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    private class Adapter_pendientes extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter_pendientes.ViewHolder> {
        private List<String> data;
        private int selectedPosition_pendientes = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
        private int alturaElemento = GridLayoutManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        public void setSelectedPosition_pendientes(int position) {
            selectedPosition_pendientes = position;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
        public Adapter_pendientes(List<String> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_comandas_pendientes, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }
        public void actualizarAlturaElemento(int nuevaAltura) {
            alturaElemento = nuevaAltura;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        private int getScreenWidth() {
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            return displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.textView_pendientes.setText(data.get(position));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams parametros = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    /*width*/ RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    /*height*/ RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
            holder.textView_pendientes.setLayoutParams(parametros);
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMargins(3, 3, 3, 3);
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
            if (position == selectedPosition_pendientes) {
                holder.textView_pendientes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_border_comanda);
            } else {
                holder.textView_pendientes.setBackgroundResource(0);
            }
            int screenWidth = getScreenWidth();
            int itemWidth = screenWidth / 5;
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.width = itemWidth;
            holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
        }
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView textView_pendientes;
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                textView_pendientes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewcomandas_pendientes);
                textView_pendientes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int previousSelectedPosition = selectedPosition_pendientes;
                        selectedPosition_pendientes = getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();
                        notifyItemChanged(previousSelectedPosition);
                        notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition_pendientes);
                    }
                });
                textView_pendientes.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            int itemCount = adapter_pendientes.getItemCount();
                            switch (keyCode) {
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                                    if (selectedPosition_pendientes > 0) {
                                        selectedPosition_pendientes--;
                                        rv_pendientes.smoothScrollToPosition(selectedPosition_pendientes);
                                        adapter_pendientes.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                                    if (selectedPosition_pendientes < itemCount - 1) {
                                        selectedPosition_pendientes++;
                                        rv_pendientes.smoothScrollToPosition(selectedPosition_pendientes);
                                        adapter_pendientes.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                                    //showAlertDialog(selectedPosition);
                                    break;
                                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TAB:
                                    adapter_atenciones.setSelectedPosition_atenciones(0);
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"TAB a Atenciones",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Este es la tarea que ejecuta cada 10 segundos y pasa el foco al primer recycler a pesar que le digo que lo pongo en el segundo despues de la actualizacion:

```
public void ejecutarTarea() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                View focusedChild_pendientes = rv1.getFocusedChild();
                if (focusedChild_pendientes != null) {
                    int position_pendientes = rv1.getLayoutManager().getPosition(rv1.getFocusedChild());
                    Adapter_pendientes.ViewHolder holder = (Adapter_pendientes.ViewHolder) rv1.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position_pendientes);
                    // Ahora puedes acceder al elemento que tiene el enfoque a través del ViewHolder
                    View focusedItemView = holder.itemView;
                }else{
                    int position_pendientes =RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
                }
                View focusedChild_atenciones = rv2.getFocusedChild();
                if (focusedChild_atenciones != null) {
                    int position_atenciones = rv2.getLayoutManager().getPosition(rv2.getFocusedChild());
                    Adapter_atenciones.ViewHolder holder = (Adapter_atenciones.ViewHolder) rv2.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position_atenciones);
                    // Ahora puedes acceder al elemento que tiene el enfoque a través del ViewHolder
                    View focusedItemView = holder.itemView;
                }else{
                    int position_atenciones =RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
                };



                Log.e("POST","Item Pendientes antes: "+selectedPosition_pendientes);
                Log.e("POST","Item Atenciones antes: "+selectedPosition_atenciones);
                if (layout_historico==true){
                    consulta_historico();
                    cl_estados.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cl_estados_historicos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else {
                    consulta();
                    consulta_atencion();
                    cl_estados.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cl_estados_historicos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    adapter_pendientes.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter_atenciones.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }



                if (selectedPosition_pendientes != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

                    Log.e("POST","FOCO EN PENDIENTES");
                    rv1.requestFocus();
                    rv1.scrollToPosition(selectedPosition_pendientes);
                    adapter_pendientes.setSelectedPosition_pendientes(selectedPosition_pendientes);
                    adapter_pendientes.notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition_pendientes);
                }
                if (selectedPosition_atenciones != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    rv2.requestFocus();
                    Log.e("POST","FOCO EN ATENCION");
                    rv2.scrollToPosition(selectedPosition_atenciones);
                    adapter_atenciones.setSelectedPosition_atenciones(selectedPosition_atenciones);
                    adapter_atenciones.notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition_atenciones);
                }


                handler.postDelayed(this, TIEMPO);
            }
        }, TIEMPO);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que los dos `RecyclerView` comparten el mismo enfoque, por lo tanto, si estás usando un `LinearLayout` vertical como contenedor, te sugiero usar los atributos `android:nextFocusDown` y `android:nextFocusUp` para cada `Recycler`, esto provocará que cada `Recycler` tenga su propio enfoque.

Realiza el siguiente cambio.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvpendientes"
    ...
    ...
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/rvantenciones" 
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvantenciones"
    ...
    ...
    android:nextFocusUp="@+id/rvpendientes" 
 >
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Gracias Jorge, ya puedo recorrer los item de ambos recyclerview e intercambio entre ellos el foco con la tecla TAB para recorrer el que necesito.
pero tengo el problema de que quiero que se mantenga el foco en el item que esta seleccionado después de la actualización de los datos que lo hago cada 10 segundos llamando a la base de datos.
se como obtener el item que tiene el foco y se mantiene mientras este en el primer recyclerview pero si estoy en el segundo recyclerview al realizar la actualización con notifyDataSetChanged() el foco se va si o si al primero.

Comment: edito mi pregunta para agregar el código de esa tarea.